# Oracle use index in where

Tags: oracle

I have a functional index on a table where the index is the decimal value of an hexadecimal column.

How can use this index in a where clause where I can use decimal value to filter the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the same expression in your WHERE clause that you used to build your function based index.